# How to get audio dictation for Siri Shortcuts under iOS13.6.1?

Tags: swift, ios13, siri, sirishortcuts

Using iOS 13.6.1

I am still waiting for Siri Shortcuts to be callable by audio dictation AGAIN (as it used to be under iOS12). Why did Apple go a less userfriendly path ?

I only get the text-input modal sheet (as can be seen in the screenshot below)

[image]

But I would like the audio dictation, how do I achive this in iOS 13.6.1 ?

My code to call the Siri Shortcuts ViewController is as follows:

```
extension EditMediaViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButtonDelegate {
    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    func present(_ addVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(addVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @available(iOS 12.0, *)
    func present(_ editVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        present(editVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is how it would look like as desired :

How can I achive this in iOS13.6.1 ??

[image]